# Error running Laravel 9.51.0 in Docker with PHP 8.2.2

Tags: laravel, docker

I have a:

- Ubuntu 20.0.4
- Docker 20.10.18, build b40c2f6

I got Laravel using the following command: `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash`

Then I run `cd example-app/ && ./vendor/bin/sail up` to run the example-app I got the following error opening http://localhost/ in a browser:

> The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Invalid argument The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file

How can I fix the error above? What is wrong with my local dev environment setup?

Running command `vendor/bin/sail up` generates the error I don't know how to fix.

Comment: Did you check the permissions for that file? If you haven't changed anything on your own, but solely use existing code, you should better report this as a bug at their issue tracker

Comment: @NicoHaase , log file storage/logs/laravel.log does not exists, the parent folder storage/logs has 777 permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've runned command: `chmod -Rv 777 /var/www/html/storage/logs/` and it has solved this errors.
Now Laravel app loading normally.